# Performance of mixing colors vs mixing colored shaders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, performance

Is there a performance difference between these two setups?[image]

I imagine on a material this simple, there's not going to be much of a difference. But on a complex material, it could. If you had a choice between a simple mask between two different complex shaders, or a bunch of masks between different properties of the same shader, is there an advantage?

Answer (score 5):

If there is, it's a pretty subtle difference.

I rendered 5 frames without the mix shader setup and 5 frames for the mixRGB node setup, and averaged the times for each. The results:

Mix Shader: `23.021`
Mix RGB: `22.78`

Comment: Yeah, it's probably too simple to see much. Have updated question.

Comment: is the result also the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I think it is still relevant.
I experimented a bit with the materials from your question. I made two render layers with a cube, both identical except for the material. I rendered them, used a *math* node set to *difference* to get the difference between both layers, and multiplied the result by 20000000. This was the final result:

[image]

In short, there is no visible difference between both materials.